# How do I add p-values to my ggplot using the geom_signif command?

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value

I am trying to add p-values to my ggplot bar plots. I do not want to use the built in significant tests through geom_signif
I have calculated the p value through t.test and want to add that to my plot.

```
anno = t.test(Slc22a18~Treatment, data = Genes, var.equal = T)
```

Code for my plot is

```
Slc22 = ggplot(data = Genes, aes(x = Treatment, y = Slc22a18, fill = Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(1), width = 0.3) +
 scale_fill_manual(values = c('lightsalmon', 'orangered3')) +
geom_point() +
theme_minimal() +
labs(y = 'Relative Expression') +
ggtitle('Slc22a18') +
geom_signif(annotations = anno$p.value)
```

When I run this code I get this error -

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_signif()`:
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 3
```

When I run the code without geom_signif() it works just fine.

Comment: I think you have to specify the location (position) of the annotation inside `geom_signif()`.

Comment: That seemed to have worked. Thanks.